# How does @Html.DisplayForModel() know the underlying data model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It looks like a magic for me that @Html.DisplayForModel() can render the markup automatically without requiring me to explicitly pass the data model to it.

How does @Html.DisplayForModel() know the underlying data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it uses @Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata internally to get the necessary information about your model. ModelMetadata has information about all the properties in your model, validation attributes, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, esentially it iterates

```
<% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay                         && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) { %>
```

See Brad Wilson's excellent blog http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html